# Shrink inline block element if it can't fit the container having another absolute element inside

Tags: css, compass-sass

I have two inline block elements placed next to each other in the parent container. 
For the sake of easier explanation, let's say that the first one contain file name and the second one contain some tags.

It's possible that content of the first one will be too long to fit inside it. It can happen if content is longer than the parent container's width or if the second element occupy too much space. In both these cases I'd like the first element to shrink automatically.

Usually, it's pretty easy to be done. The trick is that:

- it's possible that the second element (tags) will be empty (can't have fixed
  width)
- second element (tags) should be aligned to the right (I do it with absolute position now).

Sometimes it's better to use image instead of words, so here you go:
[image]

Behind the scenes it's just:

```
<div class="document-belt">
  <a class="link">some_very_looong_file_name.txt</a>
  <div class="tags">sometag</div>
</div>
```

and

```
.document-belt {     
    width:250px;
    position:relative;

    white-space: nowrap;    
}

.link {
    display: inline-block;        
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.tags {
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vTm75/

How to make the first element (`.link`) shrink automatically if its content can't fit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch the order of your elements so that the "tags" element is first:

```
<div class="document-belt">
    <div class="tags">sometag</div>
    <a class="link">some_very_looong_file_name.txt</a>
</div>
```

Then the following will work:

```
.document-belt { 
    overflow:hidden; 
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width:250px;
}

.link {
    display: block;        
    margin-left:0px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.tags {
    float:right; 
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vTm75/11/